# LINQ returning only rows without any null fields, how to get the null fields too?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

The following LINQ statement only returns all rows where there is no field of null. I don't understand why and I need all rows, not just the ones where everything is set. Any ideas?

```
var caseList =
            (from p in GetPersonList()
             join c in backEnd.GetCarList()
                 on p.PId equals c.PId
             orderby p.PId descending
             select new Person
             {
                 PName = p.PName,
                 PId = p.PId,
                 CModel = c.CModel,
             }).ToList();
        return personList;
```

I think the problem is that this isn't an outer left join, but when I try that the c.CModel won't work. It says that "c" does not exist in the current context. I think I can do something like `select new Person { Person p, Car c }` to make it work, but I've tried google it and can't find how to do it properly.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Null fields where? In which properties? Are you certain they are null?

Comment: Well, I only get the rows where no field is empty, although I know many rows have some columns that are empty. Not sure how to explain further.

Comment: What is the source? If this is translated into SQL, don't forget that null != null, so your inner join will never find a matching record if PId is null.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten I'm using MySQL, although I think I might have zoomed in to the problem. Please, see update.

Comment: If you don't ask for them, they will come as `null`. Notice that your query is creating a new `Person`, and it's probably an `Anonymous Class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from p in GetPersonList()
    join c in backEnd.GetCarList()
     on p.PId equals c.PId
        into joinResults
    from c in joinResults.DefaultIfEmpty()
    orderby p.PId descending
    select new Person
    {
        PName = p.PName,
        PId = p.PId,
        CModel = c == null ? ( CModel )null : c.CModel,
    }).ToList()
```